# Printing numbers that dot is before thousands and comma before cents

Tags: c#, numbers

I have `50172,40` and `500,00`. I would like to print them as `50.172,40` and `500,00` in C# (dot before thousands and comma before cents).

What I have tried:

```
public static string ToBankString(this decimal value)
{
    return value.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

But I get `50,172.40` (dot and comma are in wrong order). What can I do?

Comment: *you* have asked it to use the `InvariantCulture`, yet you're surprised when it doesn't follow some other culture settings?

Comment: In what culture are numbers displayed as "50.172,40" ?

Comment: @LucMorin, Many European cultures display the thousands separator as a dot and the decimal separator as a comma.

Comment: You could use `DE-DE` as culture.

Comment: @ColinMackay My question was rhetorical, trying to get the OP to understand what he was doing wrong ;-) I didn't think it would sound like "uhh... are other countries using a different way of displaying numbers ?". I'm perfectly aware of that.

Comment: @LucMorin I've noticed Socratic questions like that are easily misinterpreted on sites like this. I've learned to always make the intent of such questions abundantly clear, for example, you could precede it with "Here's a hint: ..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your own `NumberFormatInfo` and use that to format the number:

```
var value = 50172.40M;
var numberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N2", numberFormat));
```

This will write `50,172.40`.

But perhaps you should use the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` because that defines how the user prefer to format numbers? This `CultureInfo` is the default used if you do not specify any in `ToString`.

Comment: Obviously, it is correct answer for OP, but is not good idea to do so. IMO the culture specific data must be appear as mentioned in the `Contol Panel` i.e. as in `CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: `CurrentUICulture` is the language version of you Windows, not the culture the user has selected to format numbers so you should rarely use the culture to format dates and numbers. `CurrentCulture` which I suggest using is often a good choice.

Comment: Of course you are right, I have missed the last phrase in your answer, and of course I meant the `CurrentCulture`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which formats numbers like that.

You should supply your own culture instead. You could:

1. use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` or if you want the format to be dependent on the culture set in the OS your program is running on.
2. set the culture yourself, if you want to make sure it's always formatted your way, regardless of the culture set in the OS. For example `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("it-IT")`
3. create your own `NUmberFormatInfo` as per Martin's answer.